# How do I read args passed to the constructor and args passed by `use Module` in Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Currently I am making a new module and I was wondering how could I implement in my module 2 things.

We often see the `use` like:

```
use My::Module qw(something);
```

for example:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

1. **So the first question is, how do i
   retrieve this, i mean wether the
   user has specified anything and what
   he specified ?**
2. **Second question is, How do i pass and read the args
   directly on the constructor like
   this:**

   my $my_module = My::Module->new(arg1,arg2,arg3);

AS requested on the comment the simple module test code:

```
package My::Module;

# $Id$

use strict;
use Carp;

sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = {};

        $self->{ARG1}         = undef;
        $self->{ARG2}         = undef;
        $self->{ARG3}         = undef;
        $self->{ARG4}         = undef;

        bless($self,$class);
        return $self;
}

sub arg1 {
        my $self = shift;
        if (@_) { $self->{ARG1} = shift }
        return $self->{ARG1};
}

sub arg2 {
        my $self = shift;
        if (@_) { $self->{ARG2} = shift }
        return $self->{ARG2};
}

sub arg3 {
        my $self = shift;
        if (@_) { $self->{ARG3} = shift }
        return $self->{ARG3};
}

sub arg4 {
        my $self = shift;
        if (@_) { $self->{ARG4} = shift }
        return $self->{ARG4};
}

sub dump {
        my $self = shift;

        require Data::Dumper;
        my $d = Data::Dumper->new([$self], [ref $self]);
        $d->Deepcopy(1);
        return $d->Dump();
}

1;  # so the require or use succeeds
```

Comment: The second part of your question isn't entirely clear to me. Could you maybe rephrase it, or possibly include some real code, things you tried and that didn't work as you expected, etc?

Comment: I did'nt tried anything as i don't know how do i read it in this case on the constructor. All i have is a simple test module i did to test these i will update with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import` subroutine gets the arguments passed in a `use`. The following code samples should help you.

**File: My/Module.pm**

```
package My::Module;

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub import {
    my ( $package, @args ) = @_;

    print Dumper \@args;
}

1;
```

**File: module.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use My::Module qw(something);
```

If you are programming an object oriented module, you may try [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) which will save you lots of time.

Comment: awesome, really appreciated. I will take a look at Moose.

Answer (score 6):

`perldoc -f use` explains that the [`use` keyword](http://p3rl.org/use) is simply loading a module during compile-time, and then calling `->import` on it. The arguments a caller gave to the `use` statement will be passed to the import method call.

As for your second question: constructors are just methods. Getting their arguments works like it does for any other method or function, using the [`@_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARG).